# I cannot access state object in my React Redux application

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to React and Redux and I'm building a simple SPA where I'm adding projects to a list via input form. I initialized the state, I have 2 default project values and I'm successfully adding projects, but when I want to remove an object in the reducer I cannot access state.projects it says that is undefined and I cannot understand why. Can you help me please?

This is my reducer:

```js
const projects = (state = 'ADD_PROJECT', action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_PROJECT':
            return [
            ...state,
            action.payload
        ]
        case 'REMOVE_PROJECT':
            console.log(state.projects);
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                projects: [state.projects.filter(project => project.id !== action.payload.id)],
             })
        default:
            return state
} 
export default projects
```

This are the actions

```js
export const addProject = (project) => {
    return {
        type: 'ADD_PROJECT',
        payload: project
    }
}

export const removeProject = (id) => {
    return {
        type: 'REMOVE_PROJECT',
        payload: id
    }
}
```

This is how I create the store and the initial state

```js
const initialState = { 
    projects: [{
        id:100, 
        name:"Project 1"
    },{
        id:101,
        name:"Project 2"
    }] 
};

let store = createStore(projectApp, initialState, 
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && 
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
         <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems there's an extra bracket when filtering out projects. Also the payload is `id` itself (id === action.payload). Try this in `REMOVE_PROJECT` reducer :

```
projects: state.projects.filter(project => project.id !== action.payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit difficult to know what's going on without seeing what your store state is after you have added your projects.

However, it seems as though you are not adding the projects to the correct part of the state. Try changing the code for the  `ADD_PROJECT` case to this:

```js
case 'ADD_PROJECT':
  return [
    ...state.projects,
    action.payload
  ]
```

Comment: sure, I am not sure how to do that here on StackOverflow as I can't find a way to start a chat with you. But you can join the Reactiflux discord channel (https://www.reactiflux.com/) and ping me in one of the help channels using my name @Christos

Answer (score 0):

Your initial state is an OBJECT with a projects ARRAY, but when you ADD_PROJECT you return an ARRAY of your state plus the new project.  You must return the same format:

```
 case 'ADD_PROJECT':
            return {
            ...state,
            projects: [
               ...state.projects,
               action.payload
            ]                
        }
```